# Can I split this two-variable for loop into two nested loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I would like to know about the given `for` loop which looks weird to me:

```
for (int i = 0, j = s.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
```

So far, I was using for loop with one variable. However in this example there are two variables within one loop.

Can I split the `for` loop into two nested loops?

```
for (int j = 0; j < s.length - 1; j--) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    }
}
```

Comment: That first loop is a perfectly valid `for` loop. There is no need to change it at all. I bet that all Java code looked weird to you when you first started, right? Did you also try changing the Java code then, just because it looked weird to you? No, you learned some Java and it stopped looking weird. Same here. Don't change the code because it looks weird, **learn more Java** and it'll look normal to you, and the code will continue to function as it was *intentionally* written to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is wrong conversion, correct one will be:

```
int j = s.length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    // inside logic
    j--;
}
```

Comment: Note that it'll get trickier if the loop has any `continue` statements because then `j--` will be skipped. I'd advise the OP get comfortable with the original loop's syntax as that's the best way to write it.

Answer (score 2):

No.
The original acts like this:

```
sssssss
i     j

sssssss
 i   j

sssssss
  i j

sssssss
   i
   j
```

It has for example (s.length)/2 iterations. And iterates over one half with i and the other half with j.

The proposed alternative is 2D and has for example (s.length*s.length)/2 iterations (and that is assuming `j++` instead of the broken `j--`). It covers something of a triangle.

```
sssssss
j
ij
iij
iiij
iiiij
iiiiij
iiiiiij
```